# PHP Mysql Prepared statement different result

Tags: php, mysql

I have this mysql query in php:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT id, nazev, poradi FROM system WHERE id IN($idIs) ORDER BY poradi";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
```

The variable $idIs is a string '2,3' (two ids of system).
When I try to fill array $nazevSystemu, there are two values (beacause of the two ids from $idIs)

```
$i = 0;
$nazevSystemu = [];
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
  $nazevSystemu[$i] = $row2['nazev'];
  echo $row2['nazev'];
  $i++;
}
```

Result of echo $row2['nazev'];:
Value1Value2

I want to make it safe, avert SQl inj., so I use prepared statement like this (instead of the first two rows of code on this page):

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, nazev, poradi FROM system WHERE id IN(?) ORDER BY poradi");
$stmt2->bind_param("s", $idIs);
$stmt2->execute();
$result2 = $stmt2->get_result();
```

But now I get only this as result of echo $row2['nazev']; - just one value:
Value1

What did I do wrong in prepared statement?

Comment: Check the second part of the accepted answer of the duplicate. This gives a good example of how to dynamically bind params in an `WHERE IN ()` clause

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide all id's as individual parameters.
So instead of IN(?) you have to write IN(?,?,?) and parse each parameter individual.

Code example:

```
$ids = explode(',', $idIs);
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, nazev, poradi FROM system WHERE id IN(".trim(str_repeat('?,', count($ids)), ',').") ORDER BY poradi");
foreach ($ids as $id) {
   $stmt2->bind_param("i", $id);
}
$stmt2->execute();
$result2 = $stmt2->get_result();
```

Comment: I cant do that. I dont know how many ids will be there...

Comment: You can split the ids automatically.
So explode the $idIs variable into an array (using explode() function) and then auto-fill the questionmarks. Something like `('.trim(str_repeat('?,', count($ids)), ',').')`.

Comment: I have added a code example to the original answer now.

Comment: already in comma seprated 
please check this line in his questions: The variable $idIs contains string '2,3' (two ids of system). When I try to fill array $nazevSystemu, there are two values (beacause of the two ids from $idIs)

Comment: Can u pls check your answer, maybe there is some syntax mistake with brackets on line 2?

Comment: There was an bracket-syntax error in the code example. This is fixed now. Since the $idIs is a comma separeted string we must explode it as we need it as an array.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in ..."

Comment: I have changed the code example once again. When the prepare() method returns false there is probably a mistake in the query sentence. This was also the case here.

Comment: It still doesnt work, same error. Leave it, they closed this question anyway. Thanks 4 trying to help...:)

Comment: So what you want to do is debug the query for syntax errors. I did remove a comma now. Please try my new edit.

Comment: The reason we provide duplicate page closures is not to silence the asker.  It is to provide you with solutions.